# How to rotate logs in Node-RED?

Tags: logging, node-red, log-rotation

How to rotate log files in Node-RED?
I will be writing Node-RED logs to a log file. But I want a new file to be created/replace the existing file when it reaches a particular time or size limit.
How can I achieve this like I do in Java and other programming languages?

If my approach is wrong in this scenario, please advice the right approach.

Comment: You'll need to edit the question to explain a little more about what you are doing. Do you mean Node-RED's log files or a file you are writing with something like the file-out node?

Comment: maybe you should give a try to [logrotator package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/logrotator)